# How do I output a recursive list of files to a text file without using glob (python3.4)

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to recursively go through all the directories in the "boards" directory and find files that end in '.vhd' and then output them to a text file. I am using python 3.4 so I don't have access to recursive glob.

```py
path = '../../boards'

rel_paths = open('rel_paths.txt', 'a+')

files = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
    for f in files
        if f.endswith('.vhd')]
```

I want 'rel_paths.txt' to look like this in the inside:

../../boards/foo/bar/file_name1.vhd
../../boards/foo/bars/file_name2.vhd

Comment: Basically you cannot do multiline list comprehension.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Yes you can.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are flexible you can use Unix command  " find " instead of writing python code as follows

```
find ../../boards -name "*.vhd" >>  rel_paths.txt
```

it can be modified to suit what you need

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about that, I just used find in a subprocess call and it worked well enough for me.